# How to keep parenthesis in Notepad++ regex find/replace

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I'm trying to convert

LIGHTING-W/AREA  =  ( 1.7549 )

To

LIGHTING-W/AREA  =  ( 1.2 )

Using the notepad++ regex find/replace tool

When I use

LIGHTING-W/AREA  = (.*)  and replace with LIGHTING-W/AREA  = ( 1.2 )

I get LIGHTING-W/AREA  =  1.2 instead of LIGHTING-W/AREA  =  ( 1.2 )

What happened to my paranthesis and how do I get them back?  Sorry, not a programmer by trade!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use LIGHTING-W/AREA = \( 1.2 \) in your replace box

Comment: Perfect! Now why did that work?  I'm guessing parenthesis are special characters that have to be treated differently in searches?

Comment: exactly, the backslashes 'escape' the parenthesis making regex treat it as text to look for.